# How to pipe Bwa-mem output without saving SAM file

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I'm trying to find circular ARN using the program CIRI2. CIRI2 takes as input SAM file from BWA-mem, but I would like to go straight to CIRI2 output without saving SAM file.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is an English language list. Do you by any chance mean RNA rather than ARN? And although I may be wrong, I think you are more likely to get an answer on SE Bioinformatics than here.

Answer (score 2):

I never used CIRI2 but I think you can do the same way as I used to pipe with samtools:

`bwa mem genome.fa reads.fastq | samtools sort -O BAM -o output.bam -`

So it would be something like:

`bwa mem genome.fa reads.fastq | CIRI2 <your options>`

I think you will need to precise that CIRI2 input is STDIN.
I hope it will help,